# Proving inequality $\left( \frac {x} {y}\right) ^{x}\left( \frac {1-x} {1-y}\right) ^{1-x}\geqslant 1$ for $x, y\in (0, 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x,y\in \left( 0;1\right).$ I want to prove that

$$\left( \dfrac {x} {y}\right) ^{x}\left( \dfrac {1-x} {1-y}\right) ^{1-x}\geqslant 1$$

Comment: Can you give some context ? where does ths question comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show $y^x(1 -y)^{1 - x} \leq x^x(1 - x)^{1-x}$ for all $0 < y < 1$, given a fixed $0 < x < 1$. So maximize $y^x(1 -y)^{1 - x}$ with respect to $y$ using your favorite maximization technique. Logarithmic differentiation works for example. You'll get $y = x$ as the max.

Comment: You must show that the extreme value exists first, $(0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: You can use the second derivative for that; the second derivative of the logarithm is always negative for example.

Comment: You can show it is a *local* max/min by using the second derivative. This does not prove that it holds for all of $(0,1)$.

Comment: If you have exactly one point $x_0$ where $f'(x_0) = 0$ and you know that $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, then $x_0$ will automatically be a global maximum; the function increases to the left of $x_0$ and decreases to the right of $x_0$.

Comment: Okay, I'm happy with that. I thought you meant use the second derivative test (at the point $x=y$).

Answer (score 3):

Using the [weighted AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality):
$$
 \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^x \left( \frac{1-y}{1-x} \right)^{1-x} \leq 
x \cdot \frac{y}{x} + (1-x)\cdot\frac{1-y}{1-x} = 1
$$
and taking the reciprocal gives the desired result.

Equality holds if and only if $\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1-y}{1-x}$, that is if $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

In information theory, the [Kullback-Liebler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (also called Kullback-Liebler
distance or relative entropy) between the probability
distributions $P$ and $Q$ of Bernoulli random variables with parameters $x$ 
and $y$ respectively is defined to be

$$D(P||Q) = x\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + (1-x)\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1-y}\right).$$
For any two distributions (not just those of Bernoulli random variables),
the Kullback-Liebler divergence is nonnegative, and is zero precisely
when $P = Q$.  See, for example, Theorem 2.6.3 in Cover and Thomas, *Elements
of Information Theory,* Wiley-Interscience, 1991.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $x$, let $f_x(y) = y^x(1-y)^{1-x}$. Then

$$f^{'}_x(y) = y^{x-1}(1-y)^{-x}(x(1-y)-(1-x)y)$$

and (with some more checking) this shows that the maximum value occurs when $x(1-y)-y(1-x)=0$, i.e. when $x=y$.

But the statement that $f_x(x) \ge f_x(y)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ is precisely what you wanted to prove. (Just divide by the RHS.)

Answer (score 0):

Take the logarithm of both sides, this is equivalent to
$$
x(\log x - \log y) + (1-x)(\log(1-x) - \log(1-y)) \geq 0
$$
for $x,y \in (0,1)$. Since $(0,1)$ is open, if the left hand side has a minimum, it occurs at a critical point. Differentiate in $y$ and set equal to $0$,
$$
\frac{-x}{y} + \frac{1-x}{1-y} = 0
$$

you will find $x = y$ is the only possibility. Differentiating in $y$ again we find
$$
\frac{x}{y^2} + \frac{1-x}{(1-y)^2}
$$
which is strictly positive at $x=y$, so this will be a local minimum.
Thus by plugging in $x=y$ we find that if there is a minimum of the left side, then it is $1$.

Next we must rule out the possibility that the function is unbounded below. Since $[\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ is compact for all $\epsilon>0$ we know that the inequality we want holds and that $1$ is the minimum on $[\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$. If the function was unbounded below, by continuity of the function we would have a point $(x_0,y_0) \in (0,1)^2$ at which the left side is less than $1$. But this contradicts the previous remark as $(x_0,y_0)$ has strictly positive distance from the boundary. Thus the function must be bounded below, and hence the inequality holds for all $x,y \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: Using Bernoulli inequality $(1 + z)^r \le 1 + zr$ for all $z > -1$ and $0 < r < 1$, we have $u^{1-v} \le 1 + (u - 1)(1-v)$ for all $u > 0$ and $v\in (0, 1)$, or equivalently $u^v \ge \frac{u}{u + v - uv}$.

Using $u^v \ge \frac{u}{u + v - uv}$
for all $u > 0$ and $v\in (0, 1)$, we have
$$\left( \frac {x} {y}\right) ^{x}
\ge \frac{x/y}{x/y + x - (x/y)\cdot x} = \frac{1}{1 + y - x} > 0$$
and
$$\left( \frac {1-x} {1-y}\right) ^{1-x}
\ge \frac{\frac{1-x}{1-y}}{\frac{1-x}{1-y} + (1 - x) - \frac{1-x}{1-y}\cdot (1 - x)} = \frac{1}{1 + x - y} > 0.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + y - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x - y} \ge 1$$
or
$$\frac{(x-y)^2}{(1 + x - y)(1 + y - x)}\ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.