# Finding solutions to $\left( \frac{p}{c} \right) ^ c \left(\frac{1-p}{1-c}\right)^{1-c} \lt 1$

Tags: inequality

I wish to find solutions $(p,c)$ for the following inequality:
$$\left( \frac{p}{c} \right) ^ c  \left(\frac{1-p}{1-c}\right)^{1-c} \lt 1$$

Given that $0 \lt c \lt p \lt 1$

Is there any general good way to find solutions to such inequalities?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179641) looks related

Answer (score 0):

Without any further restrictions solutions are easy to find. Writing
$$f(p,c) = \left(\frac{p} {c}\right) ^ c  \left(\frac {1-p}{1-c}\right)^{1-c},$$ you can simply evaluate a solution $f(0.6.0.5) = 0.979795897113271\dots$ If you fix e.g. $c=1/2$ you will get a new function 
$$f(p) = 2 \sqrt{p(1-p)}$$ and you compute explicit solutions $f(p)=a, 1/2 < p <1$ for many $a$ by solving quadratic equations.

Comment: You are correct. The question was not well phrased. I wish to find, for every p>0, such c.